# Proof that the connected components of a compact and perfect set are open.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $X$ be a compact and perfect subset of $\mathbb C$. suppose that $X$ has infinitely many connected components, i.e $X = \bigcup C_n$, where $C_n \neq \emptyset$ and $C_n \cap C_m = \emptyset$ for all $n \neq m$.
> Every component is a closed subset of $X$.

How can I proof that the components are also open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the set$$X=\left\{x+yi\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,\left(x=0\text{ or }\frac1x\in\mathbb{N}\right)\text{ and }y\in[0,1]\right\}.$$It is compact and perfect, but the subset $\{yi\,|\,y\in[0,1]\}$ is a connected component which is not an open subset of $X$.